# Unable to add text to cell in new table row Google Doc via Docs API

Tags: c#, google-docs-api

I want to insert text to cell of Google docs table but I met issue bellow:

**Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nInvalid requests[1].insertText: The insertion index must be inside the bounds of an existing paragraph. You can still create new paragraphs by inserting newlines. [400] \r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Invalid requests[1].insertText: The insertion index must be inside the bounds of an existing paragraph. You can still create new paragraphs by inserting newlines.] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]\r\n]\r\n**

Please help me!

Comment: Show your code, otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: thank you. I found other solution to resolve issue above.

Comment: Nice, could you post it as an answer? So other's can benefit from it. Cheers!

Comment: Instead of using insert method I use delete method with another template